# What is $\arctan (z_1) \pm \arctan (z_2)$ with $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

On wikipedia, there is the following identity:
$$\arctan (u) \pm \arctan (v)=\arctan \left(\frac{u \pm v}{1 \mp u v}\right)$$

However when I try some $u,v\in\mathbb{C}$ to check, the formula does not hold. Is there an equivalent formula for complex numbers?

Comment: How do you compute the arc tangent of the complex ? What kind of difference do you observe ?

Comment: $\arctan(z)$ only makes sense up to integer multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that arctan is a multivalued function.  If you want a specific function, you need to specify which branch you are using.  For example, the principal branch has real part in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.  Other branches will differ from that one by an integer multiple of $\pi$.  So the correct results are

$$\arctan(u) \pm \arctan(v) = \arctan\left( \frac{u\pm v}{1\mp uv} \right) + n \pi $$
where $n$ is an integer.  If you are using the principal branch, it is the integer needed to put the real part of the arctan on the right in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Answer (score 1):

With a calculator,

$$\arctan(1+i)-\arctan(2-i)=-0.1608752771983+0.5756462732485i,$$

$$\arctan\frac{1+i-2+i}{1+(1+i)(2-i)}=\arctan\frac{-2+9i}{17}=-0.1608752771983+0.5756462732485i.$$

In other cases, you can have a discrepancy of $k\pi$.